# Android Studio Crash on Code autocomplete

Tags: android, macos, android-studio, macos-catalina

Android Studio Crashing after press **"Ctrl + Space"**

**System Config** -  macOs Catalina 10.15 Beta

**Android Studio** - 3.4.1 and 3.5 Beta 5

I have already tried

```
Invalidate Caches/Restart
```

Comment: i think problem seems to be with all intellij product

Answer (score 7):

A workout around is to add `-Dsun.font.layoutengine=icu` to the VM options.

Which you can do via `Help > Edit Custom VM Options`.

Source: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/JBR-1639

Answer (score 4):

Yes there is issue in All intellij IDE causing crashes on Mac Os Catalina Beta 2, From the logs I see that IDE crash because of OpenJDK, Android Studio was working fine on Mac Os Catalina Beta 1, but started crashes on Beta 2, I downgraded back to Mac Os Mojave because it was impacting my production machine, I learn that never use Beta on Production machine. I advice you to downgrade your Mac Os to stable version. Or wait for intellij to update their apps to support Catalina.

Answer (score 1):

You can go to /Applications folder and right click on Android Studio then select Show Package Contents , Goto to Contents/bin/studio.vmoptions and add at the end of the file :

```
-Dsun.font.layoutengine=icu
```

Restart the IDE.

Answer (score 0):

Switching IDE java runtime to Oracle JDK 8 worked for me. To switch the IDE Java runtime:

1. Install "JB SDK Bintray Downloader" plugin ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gvnar.png)) in Android Studio
2. Follow the instructions under `All platforms: switch between installed runtimes` section to change the IDE java runtime - [instructions](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544879-Selecting-the-JDK-version-the-IDE-will-run-under)

I've been using it for 2 hours now and no crash, no slow-ness, etc.

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x2DXv.png)

1) Update your Macbook OS to get latest in my case it was : 10.15.3